# Migrate from activeperl to strawberry perl

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl, activeperl

I have a perl code that I run in windows, with activeperl 5.8 on apache2.2 and mysql as databse. I was just curious, could I migrate to strawberry perl without breaking anything in my system? How can this be done? Is there any good resource for doing this?

Comment: Yes, probably. Perl is a scripting language, and both distributions should implement it in the same way.

Comment: Is there any documentation or tutorial about that?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to reinstall all of the modules you use. Strawberry ships with everything you need to get started, many extra (non core and very useful or 'hard to build') modules, a C compiler and build tools as standard. You can run multiple perls, even on windows. Download and install Strawberry elsewhere on your system, test the new setup with your application then remove AS when you're happy.

Unlike Unix/Linux, Windows does not use perl for any OS tasks.

Comment: Can we find older version of perl with strawberry perl, in case my version does not run properly in new? i use activeperl 5.8. I once checked with version 5.10 and it works quite fine as well. I have not checked for later versions.

Comment: @Prabhu All of the releases of Strawberry can be found [here](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html). 5.8 is ancient, you should test your app with modern version, I suspect that you will not have much problems. If the behaviour of anything has changed Perl will tell you what needs to be updated, for example hash ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Load it up and try it.  There is no other way to answer this question.

There is no particular reason to expect that this would be a big deal.  The two distributions are largely compatible.  But there may be some changes needed--particularly because you are migrating from quite an old version of Perl.

Comment: I had previously tried activeperl 5.10 and it was working properly. But haven't tried for newer ones. Now, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

You are using quite old version of Perl. You might not find the version that might be compatible with the version you are using. When trying to install to new Perl version, you might break some packages. So don't expect it to run without any modifications.

Comment: Yes, I have already migrated from older version of `Perl` to newer version, to `Active Perl`. I will sometime try to migrate to `Strawberry Perl`